# Using GitHub Codespaces secrets in devcontainer.json

Tags: environment-variables, vscode-devcontainer, codespaces, github-codespaces, devcontainer

## Problem

Some [library](https://github.com/qiskit-community/Quantum-Challenge-Grader) I use requires the case sensitive environment variable `QXToken`.
When I create a [codespaces secret](https://docs.github.com/en/codespaces/managing-your-codespaces/managing-encrypted-secrets-for-your-codespaces) the environment variable is only available in uppercase (`QXTOKEN`), as the secrets are case insensitive. Therefore I want to copy the secret stored in `QXTOKEN` to the environment variable `QXToken`.

I tried to do that in the `devcontainer.json`:

```json
{
    ...

    "remoteEnv": {
        "QXAuthURL": "https://auth.quantum-computing.ibm.com/api",
        "QXToken": "${secrets.QXTOKEN}"
    },

    "updateContentCommand": "env; export QXToken=$QXTOKEN; env",
    "postCreateCommand": "env; export QXToken=$QXTOKEN; env",
    "postStartCommand": "env; export QXToken=$QXTOKEN; env",
    "postAttachCommand": "env; export QXToken=$QXTOKEN; env"
}
```

But `remoteEnv` cannot access the codespaces secrets via `${secrets.QXTOKEN}` as one would be able to with GitHub Actions and none of `updateContentCommand`, `postCreateCommand`, `postStartCommand` and `postAttachCommand` saved the environment variable persistently for the user.
Using the command `env` I see from the logs that the environment variables have been set, but already in the next command they are gone.
Even though the `postCreateCommand` is able to access the codespaces secrets according to the [documentation](https://containers.dev/implementors/json_reference/#lifecycle-scripts) I was not able to set environment variables for later usage.

For now I only see the following environment variables, but I am missing `QXToken`:

```bash
$ env | grep QX
QXAuthURL=https://auth.quantum-computing.ibm.com/api
QXTOKEN=***
```

## Question

Is there a best practice to reuse [codespaces secrets](https://docs.github.com/en/codespaces/managing-your-codespaces/managing-encrypted-secrets-for-your-codespaces) inside [`devcontainer.json`](https://docs.github.com/en/codespaces/setting-up-your-project-for-codespaces/introduction-to-dev-containers) and make them available as environment variables in the codespace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GitHub Codespaces secrets are available via `localEnv` which is a special variable used by [`devcontainer.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/devcontainerjson-reference) which provides access to environment variables on the host machine. Therefore, you can set the environment variable `QXToken` with `${localEnv:QXTOKEN}` inside `devcontainer.json`.
Furthermore, if you want to set an environment variable pointing to a path inside your repo you can use `${containerWorkspaceFolder}/path/inside/your/repo`.

```json
"remoteEnv": {
    // Use a GitHub Codespaces secret:
    "QXToken": "${localEnv:QXTOKEN}",
    // Point to a path inside your repo:
    "QISKIT_SETTINGS": "${containerWorkspaceFolder}/.qiskit/settings.conf"
}
```

For more details on the available variables in `devcontainer.json` have a look at the [documentation](https://containers.dev/implementors/json_reference/#variables-in-devcontainerjson).